# Why mix .Net Standard and .Net Core projects in one solution?

Tags: .net-core

I just started working through the Apress "Building Web Applications with Visual Studio 2017".  I am at the beginning setting up the projects.
So I set up a solution called SpyStore.
Then a .Net Core console app called SpyStore.DAL.
Then a .Net Standard Class Library project called SpyStore.Models.

My question is why would the author choose .Net Standard class library over .Net Core Class library.  Is there a difference?

What is the difference between .Net Standard and .Net Core.
And could there be a reason for him mixing Standard in all of the sudden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can visualize .netstandard as a set of APIs. It is implemented by multiple runtimes, like netframework (net461, net47 monikers for example) or netcore (netcoreapp) A lib is not an executable, so it is independent from the concrete implementation.

Because you may want to use your library in a .net framework project (or any other implementation of .net standard), targeting netstandard make sure it is fully portable to any of these implementation, where a netcoreapp lib would only be targetable from a netcoreapp project.

An app can only be netcoreapp or netcore, as it is dependent of the implementation of the framework

You can find more infos here, and which platform implements which version of netstandard:
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Thank you - this is a very helpful answer.  I don't know why he didn't say that in the book.  He has the reader create two .Net Core projects and then out of the blue a .Net Standard project.  Plus in the book the screen shot has the Standard project as a template under core and now it is actually under standard in Project -> New.  I just completed a 6 month project in VS 2015, Core 1.0.  I was definitely confused with Standard. I just fiddled around until I got it all working.  But this answer definitely helps while I follow along.

Comment: Note that .netcore 2.0 (and netstandard 2.0) were released one or two week ago.
Major change is that .net standard 2.0 app (and net core app) may now reference nuget which target classic netframework (as netstandard 2.0 has so much api, 70% of packages on NuGet.org should work properly)
More to read here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/